# Including Javascript Library in Node Express Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use the Sanford encryption library(sjcl) in my Express App.
I've tried to the following in my app.js file:

```
var sjcl = require('.lib/sjcl.js');
```

Next I try to call sjcl.encrypt in my routes/journal.js file, but get an error that it's not defined.

Next I tried requiring the the library in my journal.js file at the beginning, but get the module ./lib/sjcl.js cannot be found.

The sjcl.js library does export the sjcl object so that doesn't seem to be it.

Any ideas on how I can gain access to the sjcl library from within my routers file?

Comment: probably not .lib, but ./lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Next I try to call sjcl.encrypt in my routes/journal.js file, but get an error that it's not defined.

`require()` just returns an object representing that module.
`var x = require(...)` assigns that object to a **local** variable.
It doesn't affect other `.js` files.

> Next I tried requiring the the library in my journal.js file at the beginning, but get the module ./lib/sjcl.js cannot be found.

That would happen if your relative path is wrong.

Comment: I tried copying sjcl.js to the same directory as journal.js and changed my require to require('sjcl.js') which didn't work so I tried ('./sjcl.js") did.  I'll just have to create a separate lib folder for my routes.  Sucks as I was hoping to leave them all together.

Comment: @TimDrake: You can just `require('../../whatever')`